# Testing already implemented Push Notifications on a physical device

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I recently started working for a startup developing an iOS app. I've forked the code to my Mac and started testing it on a physical device. But, I am having a hard time figuring out why the Push notifications aren't working on my device but they work for the App Store version of the app.

This might sound dumb, but, I am really new to iOS dev and all the online resources talk about implementing them but that's not what I want.

Comment: You need to use the sandbox push servers if you aren't running a release build

Comment: What do you mean by not running a release build?

Comment: A release build is downloaded from the app store. A  build you create and install directly on your device is a test build

Comment: If I create a new APNs certificate to test the app, would that break the existing certificate on the server? Because I am using PushMeBaby to test the push notification and it needs a APNs certificate on my Mac

Comment: check this tutorial https://www.raywenderlich.com/156966/push-notifications-tutorial-getting-started